# Uninstall app before updating on Play Store (Unity package conflict)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, package, google-play

I made an app on unity and after publishing it i had to update the unity version because a conflict between libraries. This change made all package update, and when i try to install the application on a dispositive that had the previous version, it is unable to install the app even from google play because there is a package conflict. This is solved by uninstalling the app and installing the new version, but i would like to solve this problem somehow without the need from the user to see it and have to reinstall.
Any help would be apreciated.

Uninstalling the app solves the problem, but the user shouldnt have to see this error.

Comment: If Android is unable to install the app as update you have changed APK signature. Otherwise updating the app would be not a problem as the update process uninstalls the old app (but keeping the user data) and then installing the new app version. Use the correct signature (the one used by your first app versions) and everything will work.

Comment: To add what Robert said, maybe you've had a debug variant installed on the device? Google Play sometimes doesn't let you update to a release variant in that case. This won't affect your 'real' users though as they never get a debug variant in the first place.

To test that, simply install the release variant of the previous version. Google play should now successfully install the app update

Answer (score 0):

You cant install Debug or Test APK when signed AAB or apk is installed in device